# How do I prevent Git undoing my changes

Tags: git, git-merge

Recently switched from Subversion to Git, and I'm seeing the following:

- I make a change and commit.
- Someone else modifies another part of the same file, commits, and pushes.
- I pull, and this merges the source.
- Since the same part of the file is not modified, it does not show as a merge conflict.
- My change is gone.

I can kinda see why this would happen with Git and not with Subversion.  Since Git has no authoritative copy, it has less chronological information about whether you're making a change which undoes someone else's.  But I don't want this to happen, introduce bugs, and have to track them down later, as has happened to me twice already.

I haven't yet been able to reproduce this in a simple way to post.  But this must be a common problem (though a hard one to search on SO).

Thank you.

**Update:**

Thanks @jthill
Here is the output of git log --graph --oneline rev...rev ;
--describe does not appear to be a valid parameter:

```
*   db3bf80 Merge branch 'master' of //(obscured)
|\
| * a2e54a9 Fixed some tests after the percent formatter change.
| * 6d4fa0c Changed 3 more metrics from Percent to Ratio.
| * 8504823 Changed percent formatting to return 2 digits past the decimal point, instead of 1.
| * 0597c04 Set DECIMAL as a numeric type that can be averaged. Changed external hire ratio from a percent to a ratio.
* fff6167 Added new Talent Flow sql and template.
* cbca9a2 Added new Talent Flow dummy query and report constant. Added exception for "can't find template json". Added 0
```

The 3 relevant commits are:

- cbca9a2 is my changes
- 0597c04 is their changes
- db3bf80 is the merge - the difference shows my changes removed, which did not show as a conflict

---

git show:

```
$ git show cbca9a2:
diff --git a/src/(obscured)/ReportBuilder.java b/src/(obscured)/ReportBuilder.
index 37c484b..7208619 100644
--- a/src/(obscured)/ReportBuilder.java
+++ b/src/(obscured)/ReportBuilder.java
@@ -22,6 +22,8 @@ public class ReportBuilder {

        public Report build(String reportUrl) {
                ReportTemplate template = readTemplate(reportUrl);
+               if (template == null)
+                       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not find a template for report: " + reportUrl, new Nul
                return template.makeReport();
        }

$ git show 0597c04:

(does not show any changes on the relevant lines)

$ git show db3bf80
commit db3bf80db620230ebb5190f6acd33cf55a1d7a19
Merge: fff6167 a2e54a9
Author: Michael
Date:   Tue Apr 1 13:21:01 2014 -0600

    Merge branch 'master' of //(obscured)
```

---

git config:

```
$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
gui.recentrepo=C:/(obscured)
user.email=(obscured)
user.name=Michael
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=//(obscured)
remote.origin.puttykeyfile=
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
remote.originname.url=//(obscured)
remote.originname.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/originname/*
```

---

git reflog:

```
db3bf80 HEAD@{105}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'master' of //(obscured)
fff6167 HEAD@{106}: commit: Added new Talent Flow sql and template.
cbca9a2 HEAD@{107}: commit: Added new Talent Flow dummy query and report constant.
```

**2nd Update:**

^1 to ^2:

```
index 37c484b..9dcd40e 100644
--- a/src/com/opttek/optforce/data/report/ReportBuilder.java
+++ b/src/com/opttek/optforce/data/report/ReportBuilder.java
@@ -40,12 +40,13 @@ public class ReportBuilder {

                return template;
        }
-
+
+       // TODO: remove just get a key here
        private static String getWarName() {
-               Properties serverProps = new ServerContext().getServerProperties();
-               String jndi = serverProps.getProperty("war-name");
-               if (jndi == null)
+               Properties properties = new ServerContext().getServerProperties();
+               String warName = properties.getProperty("war-name");
+               if (warName == null)
                        Logging.appLog.severe("Unable to read the war-name value in server.properties");
-               return jndi;
+               return warName;
        }
 }
\ No newline at end of file
```

^2 to ^1:

```
index 37c484b..7208619 100644
--- a/src/com/opttek/optforce/data/report/ReportBuilder.java
+++ b/src/com/opttek/optforce/data/report/ReportBuilder.java
@@ -22,6 +22,8 @@ public class ReportBuilder {

        public Report build(String reportUrl) {
                ReportTemplate template = readTemplate(reportUrl);
+               if (template == null)
+                       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not find a template for report: " + reportUrl, new Nul
                return template.makeReport();
        }

@@ -40,7 +42,7 @@ public class ReportBuilder {

                return template;
        }
-
+
        private static String getWarName() {
                Properties serverProps = new ServerContext().getServerProperties();
                String jndi = serverProps.getProperty("war-name");
@@ -48,4 +50,4 @@ public class ReportBuilder {
                        Logging.appLog.severe("Unable to read the war-name value in server.properties");
                return jndi;
        }
-}
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure git doesn't do that. A specific use case (with the file and the modifications) would help.

Comment: this must be due to some kind of negligence, my guess would be someone using `--force` instead of pulling first, or someone resolving merge conflicts checking out his own version

Comment: The only time I have ever seen something like that involved a really nasty bug in an Eclipse Git plugin that would trash repo changes on an unstage.  In the situation you are describing there would not be a merge conflict, but both sets of changes would be visible.  Can you reproduce the problem locally?  If so, just post the sequence of commands used to commit, push, pull, merge, etc.  That may give us something to go on.

Comment: I checked: no --force, and no EGit (only command line and TortoiseGit)

Comment: Please supply  `git log --graph --describe --oneline` output including  the three commits you describe: the commit containing your changes, the commit containing the other person's changes, and the merge commit.  Also, please supply the output of `git show` on those three commits, and the output of `git config -l` and `git reflog` just for the sake of  completeness.  You don't have to "reproduce" anything, the complete history of exactly what happened is all right there in your repository.

Comment: @jthill I've added the information you requested - whew! it takes a lot to track something down.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: WHat was I thinking. "--decorate", not "--describe".  don't worry about it here.  There's 100 lines of reflog subsequent to your change, so I'll try it another way.

Comment: Do `git diff db3bf80^1...db3bf80^2 src/(obscured)/ReportBuilder.java` and `git diff db3bf80^2...db3bf80^1 src/(obscured)/ReportBuilder.java`.  This will show you the accumulated changes to that file contributed by each side of the merge.

Comment: @jthill I added the subsequent output in your last comment.  Beginning to lose hope... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If another people change the same part of the code, then you should have conflict when merge.
If you want to be leave alone, one solution is: 
you can create a new tmp branch for your local job, only when you job is done, you merge it into master branch. Thus no body would modify your local tmp branch.
Create branch is very easy & lightweight, it take only 1 command & 41 bytes.

Comment: My understanding is that I should not get a conflict unless Git cannot determine which change it should accept.  In other words, if changes do not conflict (say, 2 changes from different parents on the same line) there should be no merge conflict.